# How to handle a case where a particular enum type may have multiple values

Tags: angular, ionic-framework, enums

I'm still very new to Angular/Typescript. Working on an app with numerous areas throughout where you have a type of "feed" view with a heading and then individual feed items listed out as cards the user can view. The items/elements in the feed are essentially sorted out by a particular "PostType" which is an enum.

This enum has types such as "message," "announcement," "goal," "post," etc. that would determine the items you would then see in the feed. 
My problem is that we previously had three update types (update1, update2, update3) that were possible types under the PostType enum, but are now changing it so that a user can actually add one or more custom "updates" to their overall program.

So rather than the hard coded update1, update2, update3 types under the enum I am lost on how you would be able to translate this enum to allow for an update type that might have 1+ different custom types that a user would set up for a particular program.

I hope that makes sense.

This is what I have right now:

```
export enum PostType {
    Post,
    Message,
    Announcement,
    Goal,
    Update1,
    Update2,
    Update3
}
```

But I want to be able to have an indefinite number of updates that are custom as set up by the user instead of 3 hard coded enums.

What are my options here?

Comment: sounds like you need something like `custom1` and a `custom2`. Then in your html and ts, you will have to check if it is `customX` then reference the string name that is defined for that customer. And that string you are referencing should be within an object like this `{id: 1, definedField: 'custom1', name:'I am defined by a customer'}`. Other than that, I don't think you can do what you are trying to achieve  with an enum.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Enum's idea is to list every possible type in it and then use it. What you want to do is complete opposite. So either you can just set `update` instead of listing `update1`, `update2`, `update3` etc. or if this is a problem you can give `number` instead of enum, because under the hood these `update1`, `update2` etc are just increasing numbers.

Comment: Thank you for the suggestions! I was worried that might be the case. I ended up setting a limit on the number of names a user might be able to add so that I could still stick with the hardcoded update1, update2, etc. Thanks for taking the time to check this out though!